# Pass default variables to matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, parameters, default

I am creating some functions to create quality figures of a standard form using matplotlib. I typically create line plots, contour plots, etc. Is there a way to pass parameters (axis limits, tick locations, etc.) to matplotlib that instructs matplotlib to use the default values of the parameters? For example

I create a class

```
class my_class(object):
    xlimit = *something matplotlib reads as "use default"*
    ylimit = *something matplotlib reads as "use default"*
    linwidth = *something matplotlib reads as "use default"*
```

I create an instance of this class, but I only want to specify the xlimit

```
inst = myclass()
inst.xlimit = [0,1]
```

And I leave the ylimit unchanged, so matplotlib treats it as default.

I then have a function

```
def plot_func(x,y,fig,inst):

    ax = fig.gca()
    ax.set_xlim(inst.xlimit)
    ax.set_ylim(inst.ylimit)
    ax.plot(x,y,linewidth=inst.linwidth)

    return fig
```

Which I can call and pass my class instance. So far this is working for me just fine, but I have to set values for all my plotting parameters in my_class().

Is there a way to set these values in my_class() to something, so that if I decide I just want matplotlib's default calculations for things like limits, ticks, labels, etc. I can still pass these 'variables' to my function plot_func() where they will all be set and I can customize what I want, and leave everything else as default?

Just to avoid these answers, I am aware of matplotlib's rc settings, this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Did you explore [Customizing matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#customizing-matplotlib)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23484838/2823755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since almost all things in `matplotlib` are set by `kwargs`, you could define all your possible optional settings as `None`, unless you are going to set them manually.

Then, when you call `ax.plot` or `ax.set_xlim`, you can pass in your optional setting, so if the function receives the null value you get the default setting, otherwise you get your manually defined option.

```
class my_class(object):
    xlimit = (None, None)
    ylimit = (None, None)
    linewidth = None
    color = None


def plot_func(x,y,fig,inst):

    ax = fig.gca()
    ax.plot(x, y, linewidth=inst.linewidth, color=inst.color)
    ax.set_xlim(inst.xlimit)
    ax.set_ylim(inst.ylimit)

    return fig
```

Then, if we call this with the default settings, we get:

```
x = range(5)
y = range(5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
inst1 = my_class()
plot_func(x, y, fig, inst1)

fig.savefig('default_options.png')
```

[image]

Otherwise, we can change any settings we like:

```
ax.cla()

inst2 = my_class()
inst2.xlimit = [-2, 8]
inst2.linewidth = 5
inst2.color = 'r'

plot_func(x, y, fig, inst2)

fig.savefig('custom_options.png')
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very feasible solution. It may make for a messy function with all the if comparisons but it absolutely get the job done. Thanks!

Comment: I went to implement this and realized there is still a sticking point. When parameters are set inside the plt.plot() command (such as linewidth, color, contour levels, etc.) there is no way to one-by-one check to see which parameters are being set and which are still default. I have edited my question.

Comment: Ah I had tried null argument with axis limits but inside a list not tuple, that makes sense now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The key to this question is the ability to use `None` as a default. You can create your own class, but for simpler things, such as only setting axis limits, you can simply do something like the code below, no need to create and instantiate a special class.

```
    def plot_func(x,y,xlimit=[None, None],ylimit =[None, None]):

    ax = fig.gca()
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.set_xlim(xlimit)
    ax.set_ylim(ylimit)

    return fig
```

You can either call this with 
`plot_func(x,y)` when you simply want to plot without setting limits
or 
`plot_func(x,y,xlimit=[0,10])` assuming you want to limit the x range between 0 and 10 or some other arbitrary range