# Where are Matplotlib's default defaults located?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking at the documentation of [`matplotlib.pyplot.savefig`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig), and in particular of its `dpi` argument:

> The resolution in dots per inch. If *`None`* it will default to the value `savefig.dpi` in the matplotlibrc file.

Now regarding [`matplotlibrc`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file), the documentation gives a list of four locations where it is looked for: only the last one (provided by the package) is applicable to me, which is confirmed by a call to `matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()`.

However, the `matplotlibrc` provided by the package is actually [the commented out example](http://matplotlib.org/_static/matplotlibrc) provided by `matplotlib`.

My questions are:

1. Is this a documentation bug? If we follow the documentation, this is undefined behavior.
2. Where are the "default defaults" defined? Is this in yet another file somewhere, or hardcoded within the library? (I know that I can check `matplotlib.rcParams['savefig.dpi']` to get its default default value (it is `figure` in my case), I am asking where those default defaults come from.)

Comment: 1. There is a line in `matplotlibrc`: "Blank lines, or lines starting with a comment # symbol, are ignored". So, if you wish to customize some property through `matplotlibrc`, you have to uncomment it. 2. I believe https://stackoverflow.com/a/23484838/5510499 will answer your question.

Comment: My question is not about how to set default values to `matplotlib`.

Comment: Sorry, it's not quite clear what do you mean by "this" in the first question.

Comment: I am referring to the fact that the documentation seems to inply that the default value *has* to come from a matplotlibrc file, even though matplotlib still provides default values without.

Comment: As said in my answer, those values should always be identical. So in practice this statement is always true, unless some other mechanism like an interpreter or backend changes the setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matplotlib default rcParams are defined in the file `rcsetup.py`.

The default for the `savefig.dpi` of the current development version is

`'savefig.dpi': ['figure', validate_dpi],  # DPI` (currently line [1298](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/e6ef481a32ed3ec982ce4dabdc627334fb1db2e4/lib/matplotlib/rcsetup.py#L1298))

where `'figure'` means that the dpi of the figure should be used. The value of the figure dpi defaults to

`'figure.dpi':  [100, validate_float],  # DPI` (currently line [1277](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/e6ef481a32ed3ec982ce4dabdc627334fb1db2e4/lib/matplotlib/rcsetup.py#L1277))

Note however two things:

1. Those values are overwritten in case the matplotlib rc file specifies them (i.e. the respective line in the rc file is not commented out).
2. The actual values can be found using e.g.

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   print(plt.rcParams)
   ```

   Those may already differ from the default values. As an example, the Jupyter notebook sets the default dpi to 72:
   [image]

Concerning the first question, even though the values are commented out in the matplotlibrc, they should be the same as in the `rcsetup.py`. So either the value is commented out, then they still default to the values in the rc file, or they are not commented out, in which the statement is also obviously correct.