# How to change defaults in matplot lib and find specific list of rc parameters

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, default-value

I am learning matplotlib at the moment and working on changing the rcParams. The documentation on the website appears to be very sparse.

When I look [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.rc.html#matplotlib.pyplot.rc), there is only a select few examples of rc parameters that can be changed, mainly fonts or line colors, such as:

```
rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2
rcParams['lines.color'] = 'r'
```

And so forth. I am looking for ways to alter the grid and default figure size for example, but they are not listed here and are only scattered here and there across the web. I want to find a reference list of *all* the changeable parameters and their descriptions. Does such a reference exist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a complete tutorial about rc params: [Customizing Matplotlib with style sheets and rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html).

Further down that tutorial there is a section [A sample matplotlibrc file](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file), which contains all valid rc params.

Another option is to just print all rc params out,

```
print(plt.rcParams)
```

---

Concerning the actual question:

- The grid can be turned on via

  ```
  plt.rcParams["axes.grid"] = True
  ```
- The figure size can be set via

  ```
  plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (8,6)
  ```

Comment: The above being said, I would like to know what problems you faced searching for this information. Is there any way we could improve the documentation at this point?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#matplotlibrc-sample), you can find the location of the matplotlibrc on your machine as follows:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
```

In your text editor, you can uncomment the preset commands. This file is read whenever matplotlib is imported.

Comment: you may find optional information regarding matplotlibrc in https://stackoverflow.com/q/23483857/5202571